# adding 'nofollow' to my amazon affiliate links breaks the link

Tags: html, href, nofollow

So, this is driving me insane.
On my website http://http://danidolldesigns.com/resources/bullet-journal-resources/ I was attempting to add a bunch of amazon affiliate links. I have been using the 'text only' option amazon offers when creating the link.
I copy and paste the link into my webpage, which works fine. But as soon as I edit the code to add 'nofollow' to it, it changes the link to a webpage that doesn't exist...example below:

original code:

```
    <a href="https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B000WH2X10/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&amp;camp=1634&amp;creative=6738&amp;creativeASIN=B000WH2X10&amp;linkCode=as2&amp;tag=danidolldes06-21&amp;linkId=5e049dc32f974304c20e04c605e1232a" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Faber-Castell Water Colour Pencils (Pack of 24)</a>
```

but when changed to:

```
    <a href="https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B000WH2X10/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&amp;camp=1634&amp;creative=6738&amp;creativeASIN=B000WH2X10&amp;linkCode=as2&amp;tag=danidolldes06-21&amp;linkId=5e049dc32f974304c20e04c605e1232a" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener">Faber-Castell Water Colour Pencils (Pack of 24)</a>
```

the link then sends you to "danidolldesigns.com/"https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B000WH2X10/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1634&creative=6738&creativeASIN=B000WH2X10&linkCode=as2&tag=danidolldes06-21&linkId=5e049dc32f974304c20e04c605e1232a"

Which obviously doesn't exist.

Hope i've explained this okay, sorry if it's hard to understand. I tried downloading a nofollow plugin to see if I could use that instead of doing it manually but still had the same outcome. I'm all out of ideas so any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Reproduce in a jsfiddle or something

Comment: unfortunately I have no idea how to do that :/